# Office layout example. JLabels don't show up in JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, japplet

I have searched (I think) thoroughly for an answer to my problem. I'm a beginner so I may just not know what to look for. I am trying to make an overview of an office layout (tables, chairs), which I coded using Graphics2D and GeneralPath, and JLabels with names by each chair.
If this has already been answered I apologize but I did look.
(Note: the graphics are super simple for now: table is just a square and chairs are just lines.)

public class DemoReception extends JApplet{

```
@Override    
public void paint(Graphics g){
    //draws table
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f));
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int[] xPoints={150,700,700,150};
    int[] yPoints={250,250,550,550};
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD,xPoints.length);

    path.moveTo(xPoints[0], yPoints[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.length; i++) {
        path.lineTo(xPoints[i], yPoints[i]);
    }
    path.closePath();
    g2.draw(path);

    //draws chairs
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    path = new GeneralPath(GeneralPath.WIND_NON_ZERO);
    path.moveTo(260,240);//Person1
    path.lineTo(310,240);

    path.moveTo(510,240);//Person2
    path.lineTo(560,240);

    path.moveTo(260,560);//Person3
    path.lineTo(310,560);

    path.moveTo(510,560);//Person4
    path.lineTo(560,560);
    path.closePath();
    g2.draw(path);                               
   }
```

And here is the main method:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int labelwidth = 50;
    int labelheight = 10;

    JFrame testFrame = new JFrame("Test Layout");
    testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JApplet demo = new DemoReception();
    testFrame.setBackground(Color.white);
    testFrame.getContentPane().add(demo);
    testFrame.pack();
    testFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000,710));
    testFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1000,710));

    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.setAlignmentX(0);
    testPanel.setAlignmentY(0);

    label1 = new JLabel("Person1");
    label2 = new JLabel("Person2");
    label3 = new JLabel("Person3");
    label4 = new JLabel("Person4");

    label1.setAlignmentX(260);
    label1.setAlignmentY(235);
    label1.setSize(labelwidth, labelheight);
    label1.setVisible(true);        
    testPanel.add(label1);

    label2.setAlignmentX(510);
    label2.setAlignmentY(235);
    label2.setSize(labelwidth, labelwidth);
    label2.setVisible(true);
    testPanel.add(label2);

    label3.setAlignmentX(260);
    label3.setAlignmentY(565);
    label3.setSize(labelwidth, labelwidth);
    label3.setVisible(true);
    testPanel.add(label3);

    label4.setAlignmentX(510);
    label4.setAlignmentY(565);
    label4.setSize(labelwidth, labelwidth);
    label4.setVisible(true);
    testPanel.add(label4);

    testFrame.getContentPane().add(testPanel);
    testFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I run it all I get is the JFrame with the graphics but the JLabels don't show up.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your paint method need to call super.paint(g)?  Off the top of my head, it looks like your paint() override will draw the graphics, but it won't draw anything else.  It doesn't automatically do the rest of the stuff that the overridden version does.  You need to do that yourself by calling super.paint(g).  See if that works.

Comment: P.S. I've seen other answers here that recommend overriding paintComponent() instead of paint() ... sorry, I don't know if that's what you need here.  If you do, the same applies--you have to make it call super.paintComponent(g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JLabel` does not appear in the `JApplet` as `JFrame#pack` is called before all labels have been added. The result is that those components are not validated so dont appear

The solution is to invoke the method before calling `setVisible`

```
testFrame.pack();
testFrame.setVisible(true);
```

However further changes are necessary as the applet window itself will not appear when this is done. This is because the statement

```
testFrame.getContentPane().add(testPanel);
```

will cause the `JPanel` `testPanel` to be displaced as implemented in the earlier statement

```
testFrame.getContentPane().add(demo);
```

`BorderLayout` can only contain one component at the `CENTER` location.

To fix, remove the `testPanel` and add the `JLabel` components directly to the `JApplet` `demo` instead.

Also add

```
super.paint(g);
```

to the `paint` method to ensure that the `JLabels` are painted by Swing.

---

Of course `paint` should never be used for custom painting in Swing. Rather use `paintComponent`

As a future exercise, make sure to replace the `paint` functionality by using a `JComponent` based class instead and overriding `paintComponent`. Remember to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`. Follow the steps outlined in [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)